# Como retornar todos os campos de um objeto numa mutation no GraphQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

Olá,

Eu tenho uma `mutation` no `GraphQL` (Com rails) e eu quero realizar um update no banco usando essa `mutation`. Quando ele finalizar o udpate, retornasse o objeto inteiro como resposta.

Vamos lá.

Tenho uma tabela **Users** no banco de dados. Vamos dizer que na tabela desse banco eu tenha os seguintes campos:
`ID | name | birthday | phone | email`

E eu quero alterar o nome de um dele, para isso a mutation será:

```
mutation {
  updateUser(
    id: 6,
    name: "Usuário 02"
  ) {
    name
  }
}
```

Depois que eu passo o `argument: value` (name: "Usuário 02") eu posso informar quais campos eu quero na resposta dessa `mutation`.

Minha dúvida é por aí.

Eu não quero passar nenhum campo como resposta mas quando isso acontecer, quero que todos os campos da tabela sejam retornados, ou seja, o objeto completo (Pra quem ta com dúvida, User é o meu objeto rsrsrs).

Isso é possível? 
Poderia me dar uma orientação sobre como fazer?

Por favor, leiam e se não entenderam alguma parte, peço que comentem aqui embaixo que eu já tiro a dúvida :)

Grato a todos que ajudarem!

Comment: Vale a pena ler: https://productionreadygraphql.com/blog/2019-10-24-why-you-cant-select-all-fields-on-a-type-in-graphql.

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível retornar todos os campos de um objeto de forma implícita. No GraphQL você deve ser explícito com o que você quer que sua query retorne.

O que tiver de solução para isso pode ser considerado gambiarra. O mindset ao usar GraphQL é diferente.